# How can I check if a string contains a number smaller than an integer?

Tags: c#, string, integer

Having some issue with this...

```
    if (System.Convert.ToInt32(TotalCost(theOrder.OrderData.ToString()).ToString()) < 10000)
        ViewData["cc"] = "OK";
    else
        ViewData["cc"] = "NO";
```

yields: "Input string was not in a correct format."

How can I check if the number inside the string is less than 10000?

Oh yeah: TotalCost returns a ContentResult of type text/plain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to see if the string is a number that falls into the range of Int32.

If the result *is* a number, you can always compare it to whatever limit you have.

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(theOrder.OrderData, out i))
{
    if (i < 10000)
    {
       // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(TotalCost(theOrder.OrderData.ToString()));
if (value < 10000)
{
    // ...
}
```